# Query's perfomance with SQL Server Linked Servers

Tags: java, sql-server, linked-server

During my latest job I had to map some entities into my project. However, while doing so, I came up with a question I could not have answered. The thing is like this.

This entities come from a view on a external SQL Server DB, so I used a SQL's linked-server to connect my DB with theirs. So far so good.

My question actually comes up when I found out that, let's say my entity A is exactly equal to the view on the external server. And my entity B is data obtained from running a specific query over that view.

So, after this I realized I had 2 options for my entity A and one for B.

**First** : Make every query related to my A entity, to the external server. And make a view for the B entity on my own DB based on the external one.

**Second** : Make a view of their view in my own DB to use as the A entity. For the B one, I would do the same as the first option.

I chose the second one, for commodity and "unity" if you'd like to call it that way. However, I can't stop asking myself if this is a bad practice or not, or if this could bring perfomance issues. (So far so good).

I should add that both SQL Servers are under the same network, and that this DB's do not handle tons of requests nor results. The external view has 2k results to be exact.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your execution plan will hurt because of distributed query. If it is only 2k rows, I would materialize it every time to temp table and do everything on one side. `SELECT *  INTO #temp FROM linked_server.db.schema.table;   -- main  query which refers to #temp`

Comment: Forgot to add that I can't sync my DB with theirs, because of the sensitive data in their DB, they chose to not let me copy anything. (It's silly, I know, nevertheless I can't make a temp table) @lad2025

Comment: #temp table lives only per session plus you could select only columns you need